# Clean way to exit declarative Jenkins pipeline as success?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am looking for the cleanest way to exit a declarative Jenkins pipeline,
with a success status.
While exiting with an error is very neat using [error step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal) , I couldn't find any equal way to exit with success code.
E.G:

```groovy
stage('Should Continue?') {
  when {
    expression {skipBuild == true }
  }
  steps {
    echo ("Skiped Build")
    setBuildStatus("Build complete", "SUCCESS");
    // here how can I abort with sucess code?
    // Error Would have been:
    // error("Error Message")

  }
}
stage('Build') {
  steps {
    echo "my build..."
  }
}
```

For Example with a scripted build, I could achieve it with the following code:

```groovy
if (shouldSkip == true) {
  echo ("'ci skip' spotted in all git commits. Aborting.")
  currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
  return
}
```

While I am aware of the ability to add a script [step](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) to my declarative pipieline, I was hoping to find a cleaner way.

Another approach could be throwing an error and catch it somewhere down the line, but again it quite messy.

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Declarative languages do not really work this way. This is more imperative languages (as you noted, scripted does this).

Comment: Why is adding a script step not clean?

Comment: A `return` will only exit that stage, but it does not exit the entire pipeline. I am not aware of a way to exit the whole pipeline.

Comment: The fact that there's no simple way of doing this really looks like an oversight.
Having to a "skip" condition to every step in a pipeline with 10+ steps, just to cover this case is a headache.

Answer (score 7):

A solution that worked for me was to create a stage with sub-stages and put the check in the top level stage.

```groovy
    stage('Run if expression ') {
        when {
            expression { skipBuild != true }
        }
        stages {
            stage('Hello') {
                steps {
                    echo "Hello there"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I put all the stages that I want to continue inside this stage. And everything else outside of it. In your case you would put all your build stages inside the stage with when check.